# Managed ODP.NET Pooling behaviour, WCF, IIS7 don't keeping min pool size

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, odp.net, managed

When i set in connection string Min Pool Size=10, i'm expect that will create 10 sessions and keep them all time application lives.

Same application was tested on two servers with IIS7, Win2008R2. One of them 'DIRTY' have many applications running same time and other 'CLEAN' server with one tested application.
In 'CLEAN' server i saw expected behaviour of connections - on first call it open 10 connections and keep them, but in 'DIRTY' server with many applications i see unexpected behaviour - connections estabilish and closes by requests, not keeping Min Pool Size value, it can be 1 , 2, 5,8,11 connections.

Application identicaly by binary and web.config, differences can be in operation system and IIS7 configuration, but in first look it must be also identicaly.

Why connections in pool not keeping min size and do you have any ideas how to diagnose this ?

Comment: Enable connection pool performance counters to get a better idea what is really going on: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT174

Comment: Hm i try to install managed odp.net counters in 'CLEAN' server - its installed and work properly. But when i do same steps on 'DIRTY' server OraProvCfg hangs " ERROR: Encountered a problem while registering ODP counters" and i can't find detailed log of this problem and google say nothing about this.

Comment: The link I gave you does not mention "OraProvCfg.exe". Try setting the registry values manually instead of using OraProvCfg.